# docker doesn't put files into the expected mounted folder

Tags: docker

I have `Dockerfile` that looks like this

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
VOLUME /folder
WORKDIR /
ADD my_packge.whl .
RUN wget -O- "https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/stable?release=linux64-binary&source=github" | tar -zx -C /usr/local/bin && \
    apk update && \
    apk add --virtual deps gcc python3-dev linux-headers musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache bash && \
    pip install my_package.whl && \
    apk del deps
ENTRYPOINT [ "python_app" ]
```

And I execute it like this

```
docker run --rm \
        -v ${WORKSPACE}/TEST_RESULTS:/folder \
        -e CF_USERNAME=${CF_USN} \
        -e CF_PASSWORD=${CF_PWD} \
        container/${CF_SPACE}:${GIT_TAG_NAME} \
        -b 'myy_parameter'
```

I expected that the execution results will put some files into `${WORKSPACE}/TEST_RESULTS`. But it doesn't happen.

What is wrong?

Comment: The local test…results folder will be mounted into the folder directory in the image at container startup, not the other way around. So if , at startup, you have a file my file.txt in the test…results folder that will be available in the container. But if you have myfile2.txt in the container, that will not show up in the host.  Once the container is already running, if you copy myfile3.txt into /folder then that becomes also available in the host

Comment: So I need to set volume after ADD and workdir?

Comment: Think about it this way. Assume that your image is a table and the /folder directory is a box that you placed on the table. When you built your image, you put a bunch of stuff on the box. Then when you started the container, you took a new empty box (test_results folder) , placed it in the table and hid the old box under the table. Then when you try to access the contents of the box on the table, it is empty. That is what’s happening basically.

Comment: So you can either 1 put whatever files you need in the test_results directory before starting the container. Or 2 start the container , login to the container and regenerate whatever files need to be put into the folders directory. That will copy the files to your host and from the. On you can just start normally

Comment: so I cannot use ADD when I use mount?

Comment: Well depends on your use case. For example, I use volume mounts all the time during development. i still copy my code into the image in the docker file but then I mount my local code directory into the container so that I can continue to modify the code while running the container. This way once I am done coding , all I need to rebuild the image to update it with the latest code. The thing to remember is that when mounting a volume, the host folder always hide the container’s folder

Comment: What I want to achieve is basically I have a folder with the scripts needed to be executed during `docker run` (.whl tool requires certain data in certain folders) and the result of execution should be put to `TEST RESULT` folder.